# Regular expression in ruby to get all vowels in string

Tags: ruby, regex

How do you get all occurrences of vowels in a string along with its index?

> Example: str="rohan"
>   I want a result like { 1=>'o', 3 => 'a' }

Is there any method in ruby to do so or do I have to write a method for that?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Vowels are a tiny set, just do a regex global match for `[aeiou]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`$~`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+variables) ([`MatchData`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/MatchData.html)) together with [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
hash = {}
str.scan(/[aeiou]/){|m| hash[$~.begin(0)] = m }
puts hash
```

Comment: This is the one I was trying to remember.. +1

Comment: Very nice, Arie.  I wasn't aware of [MatchData#begin](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/MatchData.html#method-i-begin), which reads  "begin(n) → integer - 
Returns the offset of the start of the nth element of the match array in the string. n can be a string or symbol to reference a named capture."

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use regex here:

```
VOWELS = %w(a e i o u)
str = "rohan"
str.each_char.with_index.select { |c, _i| VOWELS.include? c }.to_h
#=> {"o"=>1, "a"=>3}
```

Or if your Ruby version doesn't have `to_h`:

```
str.each_char.with_index.each_with_object({}) do |(c, i), h| 
  h[i] = c if VOWELS.include?(c) 
end
#=> {1=>"o", 3=>"a"}
```

Comment: Michael, it appears that you intended to change the block variable `i` to `_`, but ended up with `_i`.  No reply, plz.  I'll delete this comment.

Comment: Some people use `_variable` to mark a variable that will be ignored but they still want to document what it would be (Ruby 2 supports this and won't warn on variables following that naming scheme). I wanted OP to understand that it would be the index.